# Prove $2^p + 3^p$ cannot be a perfect power

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

The question: if $p$ is a prime, prove that $2^p + 3^p$ cannot be a perfect power. So far my progress is limited to noting that:

- 5 always divides $2^p + 3^p$, so it must divide $k$ if $k^n$ is the perfect power
- $2^p + 3^p$ is 5 modulo 6
- instead of a perfect power, it is sufficient to consider a perfect prime power.

How do I proceed?

Comment: Why is it sufficient to consider a perfect prime power?

Comment: @TonyK: Fairly sure the OP means that it suffices to consider the case $2^p+3^p=k^n$ where $n$ is also a prime.

Comment: Any number which can be written $a^n$ with $n>1$ can be written as $(a^{n/p})^p$ for some prime divisor of $n$. @TonyK

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Yes, but that is not what "prime power" means. I'm sure Jyrki is right though.

Comment: "perfect prime power" in context is not referencing "prime powers" in that sense, quite clearly. Context in language is everything. @TonyK

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you point out, if $p$ is odd then your sum is always divisible by $5$.  However, (other than in the easily handled case $p=5$) it is never divisible by $25$:

$\varphi(25)=20$ so we only need to work with $p\mod 20$.    But for $p\equiv \{1,3,7,9,11,13,17,19\}$ mod($20$) we get $2^p+3^p\equiv \{5,10,15,20,20,15,10,5\}$ mod($25$).

Comment: To avoid brute force, write $2^p+(5-2)^p \equiv p2^{p-1}5\pmod{25}$ when $p>5$ odd. By the way, $2^5+3^5$ is divisible by $25$. You'll need to handle that case separately.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews   Thanks (just added a note about the case p=5).

Comment: How $p=5$ is easily handled?

Comment: @QuangHoang  Explictly.  $2^5+3^5=275$ and     $275=11*25$ is not a perfect power.

Comment: Right, what was I thinking :-)

Comment: @lulu Can you please explain why we use $\mod 20$.

Comment: @Viraam  By [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) $\gcd (a,n)=1 \implies a^{\varphi(n)}\equiv 1 \pmod n$.  So if I want to study the given expression $\pmod {25}$ it suffices to study the exponent $\pmod {20}$. Now, why $25$?  That was arrived at by writing out the first several of the terms and observing that while each was divisible by $5$ none were divisible by $25$ (other than the special case $p=5$).

Answer (score 1):

Another quick way to find that $2^p+3^p$ is never divisible by $25$ is to use LTE.

For $p \ge 7$, we have
$$v_5(2^p+3^p) = v_5(2+3)+v_5(p) = 1+v_5(p) = 1$$

This implies the desired conclusion.

Comment: LTE? What is that ?

Comment: It is a very useful lemma in number theory. The full name is Lifting the Exponent.

Comment: Except when $p=5$. Also, I think you should use \upsilon instead of v.